# How can I initiate a modem connection from the command line?

Tags: command-line

I am looking for a way to initiate a PPP connection with my EVDO modem from the command line instead of having to go to System Preferences -> Network and hit "Connect".

Comment: You might be able to use two terminal windows to determine where your pppd script is stored. One window running `opensnoop`, the other `fs_usage` (without your modem, it's hard to guess where your scripts are stored)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To connect a network device, use the `System Events` dictionary:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        connect service "Sprint 3G"
    end tell
end tell
```

assuming the name of the service is `Sprint 3G`:

[image: Screenshot of Sprint 3G]

To disconnect, change `connect` to `disconnect`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current location of network preferences
        disconnect service "Sprint 3G"
    end tell
end tell
```

Once you've saved your scripts with names, you can use the terminal `open` command to kick off either script.

Comment: Well done! I hope you don't mind me adding an open command to finish this off in the terminal way.

Comment: Looks great. I ended up using this with [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) so I could just type `connect 3g` or `disconnect 3g`.

Comment: Here's what a screenshot of the Alfred integration looks like: https://img.skitch.com/20110831-pg1nht8jbnb46nwgx27saw2uxc.png

Comment: How do you call Alfred from the command line? Perhaps you just meant to script it in response to a shortcut key.

Comment: Yes, I just mean that I was able to use the script in response to a keyword in Alfred.

Comment: alfred looks to be great - glad you have it - it might be a nice replacement for us old timers using FastScripts and storing scripts on the filesystem...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but this could be done with UI scripting.
I don't have an EVDO modem, so I can't give the specifics of the script that would work, but first you would go to  -> System Preferences -> Universal Access and make sure "Enable access for assistive devices" is checked.

Then, you could write a script using a text editor. As I said, the specifics of the script would depend on your system and the layout of the screen you're trying to control, but it would look something like this:

> #!/usr/bin/osascript
>
> tell application "System Preferences"
>
> activate
>
> set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.network"
>
> click button 1
>
> tell application "System Preferences" to quit

You'd save the script, make it executable, and then you could enable your modem from the command line. I'm sure there's a more elegant way that doesn't involve popping up a window and that doesn't involve so much trial and error at the "click button 1" stage, but this is a start.

Comment: I would really like to find a way to do it without needing to actually open the System Preferences.

Comment: Of course. As I said, my approach is distinctly inelegant, but still scriptable. I'd love to see a better answer, and I suspect something involving pppd is more likely to be viable, but I have less advice to offer on that front.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using [pppd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pppd.8.html). You'll need to find the device name (/dev/tty...) and read through the long list of available options but it looks like that could work.

Comment: I don't have a modem anymore to test this unfortunately, but I have used it in the past. (This is exactly what's used for [modem connections in linux](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5467), for example.) If this answer is "negatively helpful" I would appreciate learning why it was downvoted with a comment.